# Вызов функции при различных событиях

Tags: jquery

Добрый день

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть функция, скрипт, который выполняет переключение кнопки.
В данный момент, переключение происходит при двух событиях, а именно:

1. Клик по правой области переключает "бегунок" вправо, клик по левой области - влево.
2. Перетаскивание "бегунка" влево и вправо.

Необходимо добавить функционал и сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на сам бегунок, он также переключался.

[Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cfJGs/10/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В такой постановке в задаче противоречащие условия. Убирайте клик по сторонам бегунка, устанавливайте флаг состояния и переключайте с помощью одной функции-свитчера.

Comment: То есть, на сколько я понимаю, данное условие невозможно реализовать. Верно?

Comment: Это называется: "И рыбку съесть и на ... сесть" (прошу прощения за мой фрнцузский)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Можно повесить onclick-switcher на сам бегунок.